How to position text elements relative to LightningChartJS in a vertical layout , underneath the chart instead of the xAxis?
How to position text elements relative to LightningChartJS in a vertical layout , underneath the chart instead of the xAxis?
I'm working with LightningChartJS and facing a layout challenge. I have two text labels, "Hello" and "World", that need to be positioned vertically underneath a chart. Specifically, I want the "Hello" label to be positioned at x = -2 (or aligned to the left side of the chart) and the "World" label at x = 2 (or just to the right side of the chart). Additionally, I need the chart to allocate space for these labels similar to how space is allocated for the xAxis.
Here are some visuals representing the problem:
Problem depiction:

Current undesired state:

Desired design layout:

the code
import { useEffect } from "react";
import {
  lightningChart,
  SolidFill,
  ColorHEX,
  UIElementBuilders,
  UIOrigins,
  emptyFill,
  emptyLine,
} from "@arction/lcjs";

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const BackgroundFill = new SolidFill({
      // to optimize this I can share the same BackgroundFill object across all charts
      color: ColorHEX("#ffffff"),
    });

    const lc = lightningChart({licence: "licence"});
    const chart = lc.ChartXY({ container: "chart1" });
    chart.setTitle("");
    // Example, position UI in axis coordinates
    const axisX = chart.getDefaultAxisX();
    axisX.setVisible(false);
    axisX.setInterval({ start: -2, end: 2 });
    const axisY = chart.getDefaultAxisY();
    axisY.setVisible(false);
    const textBoxHello = chart
      .addUIElement(UIElementBuilders.TextBox, { x: axisX, y: axisY })
      .setPosition({ x: -2, y: -1 })
      .setText("Hello")
      .setOrigin(UIOrigins.LeftBottom)
      .setTextRotation(270)
      .setMouseInteractions(false);

    textBoxHello.setBackground((background) =>
      background.setFillStyle(emptyFill).setStrokeStyle(emptyLine)
    );

    const textBoxWorld = chart
      .addUIElement(UIElementBuilders.TextBox, { x: axisX, y: axisY })
      .setPosition({ x: 2, y: -1 })
      .setText("World")
      .setOrigin(UIOrigins.LeftBottom)
      .setTextRotation(270)
      .setMouseInteractions(false);

    textBoxWorld.setBackground((background) =>
      background.setFillStyle(emptyFill).setStrokeStyle(emptyLine)
    );
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div id={"chart1"} style={{ width: "200px", height: "500px" }}></div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;


Could someone guide me on how to achieve this layout in LightningChartJS? Any examples or tips would be greatly appreciated!
Update of progress:
I used this snippet :
    chart.setPadding({
      bottom: 50,
    });

it works better but! if I resize the chart height for example to 300px the text overlap the chart, I want the same solution that is being handled with the xAxis, to perfectly fit to the space underneath the chart
image where the last letter overlap

image where more letters overlap the chart

